# Why does code inside unused method run?

Tags: go

The code below comes from Todd Mcleod's Golang web-dev course. What I fail to understand - even watching his video's over and over and googling everything about methods- is the following: **The method ServeHTTP is attached to type hotdog, but is never ran. Still the code inside the method (in this case Fprintln(...) is executed.** (When you run this code and go to localhost:8080, it diesplays "Any code you want in this func".) Could anyone explain me why this is?

Thanks a lot!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
     "net/http"
)

type hotdog int

 func (m hotdog) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     fmt.Fprintln(w, "Any code you want in this func")
}

 func main() {
    var d hotdog
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", d)
}
```

Comment: Why do you say *"The method ServeHTTP is attached to type hotdog, but is never ran"* ? Did you read the documentation of the net/http package ? Do you understand the concept of *interface* ?

Answer (score 5):

It is run.  `ListenAndServe` calls it for every request made to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Since you passed `hotdog`, which implements `ServeHTTP`, as a handler, every request received will be sent to hotdog's `ServeHTTP`.

Answer (score 1):

this function is run when the type hotdog is used

```
func (m hotdog) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Any code you want in this func")
}
```

in the main you create variable d with the type hotdog,

then in the ListenAndServe and you tell your code to use variable d every time someone connects to your server and because d is of type hotdog your first function is run everytime someone connects

```
func main() {
    var d hotdog
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", d)
}
```